# How to use the below REST API ,

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, rest, curl

I have a REST API and I am trying to use it , but getting error. Directly running this on linux command line it works. Below is the API ##

```
curl -v -s --insecure -X POST -H "X-Auth-User: <groupApiId>" -H "X-Auth-Key: <authKey>" -H "X-Auth-Requester: <requesterCorpId>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"serverList\":[\"xxxxxxxx\"],\"ticket\":\"IM154587704\",\"expirationDate\":\"2015-07-28T16:36:00\",\"}" http://xxxxx.com/filters/createFilter
```

below is my code in python

```
#/usr/bin/env python


import time
import urllib
import urllib2
headers={"X-Auth-User": "xxx",
        "X-Auth-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "X-Auth-Requester" : "12345",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"}

header["X-Auth-Requester"]=username

body_content={"serverList":'yyyyyy',
          "ticket":'1234',
          "expirationDate":"2016-04-12T16:36:00"}
url="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/filters/createFilter"

body = urllib.urlencode(body_content)
req = urllib2.Request(url, body, headers)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    filter_result=response.code
    if filter_result==200:
    print(" success\n")
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print e.code
```

Comment: I am getting below errors   : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using urllib2

```
import urllib2
import json
headers = {
    'X-Auth-User': 'xxx',
    'X-Auth-Key': 'yyyy',
    'X-Auth-Requester ':'uuuu',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }

body = {"serverList":["xxxxx"],
        "ticket":cm_or_im,
        "expirationDate":"2016-04-10T16:36:00",
       }

body = json.dumps(body)


url="http://xxxxxx.com/filters/createFilter"

req = urllib2.Request(url,body,headers)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    filter_result = response.code
    if filter_result==200:
        print("success\n")
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print e.code
```

Comment: `body = str(body)` is incorrect, you need to import `json` and use `json.dumps()` to encode the data as valid JSON.

Comment: @augurar , I am new to python , can you please show me how to do in above code ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty convenient ["Convert cURL syntax to Python" service](http://curl.trillworks.com/) that would instantly convert your cURL command into Python+[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) code.

Here is what it produced (with some improvements):

```
import json
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Auth-User': '',
    'X-Auth-Key': '',
    'X-Auth-Requester': '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = {
    "serverList":["xxxxxxxx"],
    "ticket":"IM154587704",
    "expirationDate":"2015-07-28T16:36:00",
    "matchStringList":["Testing123"]
}

response = requests.post('http://mymonitoring-qa.fmr.com/filters/createFilter', 
                         headers=headers, 
                         data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: is it not possible to do with urllib and urllib2 since we do not have requests package in our servers installed . Please help with urllib and urllib2 @alecxe